# Open a new form on the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

How can I open a new form from the main thread in C#?

At this moment I open them by using this:

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(oppenMainForm));
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

But this creates a new thread... My main form is my login form.. And I want that to close and then open my second form.

Comment: Why can't you use `(new Form()).Show()`? Having two "GUI" threads is not a good idea.

Comment: @vcsjones I have gotten to know that.. So I'm trying to fix that...

Comment: @vcsjones If you do that then your login form is left hanging around for the duration of the application, despite being useless.

Comment: @Servy I hadn't really connected the dots with what was going on with the login form. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your program.cs file and alter it so that you show your login form and then, after it has been closed, determine if you should open up another form:

It'll likely look something more or less like this:

```
LoginForm loginform = new LoginForm();
Application.Run(loginform);

if (loginform.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
//TODO handle error cases
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use this

```
Application.Run(new OppenMainForm());
```